# multiple entries from csv files in java script

Tags: php, javascript

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng, 
    map: map,
    title:"Hello World!"
});

        <?php 
    $fd = fopen ("landmarks.csv", "r");
    echo "var latlngarr=new Array();";
    $i=0;
    echo "var markerarr=new Array();";

    while (!feof ($fd)) {
        $buffer = fgetcsv($fd, 4096); 

        echo "var latlngarr[$i] = new google.maps.LatLng($buffer[2],$buffer[3]);";
        echo "var markerarr[$i] = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlngarr[$i], 
            map: map,
            title:$buffer[1]";
        });
        $i++;
    }
    fclose ($fd);
    ?>
```

I want to create multiple markers in google maps..the first entry works...but the other ones, from the csv file dont work? Is there something wron with the mixed php and Javscript code?

Comment: Not sure whether this may assist you, but SitePoint did a Tutorial on how to have Google Maps pull locations for markers from an XML file using AJAX - http://blogs.sitepoint.com/google-maps-api-jquery/.
If you are planning on viewing a good number of markers, or using a database to store their details (in which case another PHP script could generate the required XML to have this data available dynamically), it may be worth a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add quotes around strings and fix missing `}`

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: myLatlng, 
map: map,
title:"Hello World!"
});

<?php 
$fd = fopen ("landmarks.csv", "r");
echo "var latlngarr=new Array();";
$i=0;
echo "var markerarr=new Array();";

while (!feof ($fd)) {
    $buffer = fgetcsv($fd, 4096); 
?>
    latlngarr[<?= $i ?>] = new google.maps.LatLng(<?= $buffer[2] ?>, <?= $buffer[3] ?>);
    markerarr[<?= $i ?>] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlngarr[<?= $i++ ?>], 
        map: map,
        title: '<?= $buffer[1] ?>'
    });
<?php
}
fclose ($fd);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that possibly the data coming out of the CSV file isn't properly quoted, particularly the `title` attribute. When dynamically building Javascript from PHP, you should always use json_encode():

```
$b2 = json_encode($buffer[2]);
$b3 = json_encode($buffer[3]);
$title = json_encode($buffer[1]);
echo "var latlngarr[$i] = new google.maps.LatLng($b2,$b3);";
echo "var markerarr[$i] = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: latlngarr[$i], 
     map: map,
     title: $title";
});
```

using json_encode guarantees that whatever is in those PHP variables will be translated into syntactically correct Javascript.

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately that doesnt seem to be the problem.

Comment: Check your javascript console for other errors as well. that's shift-ctrl-J in firefox.